# Should I check a variable for NULL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(type) values($type);
```

I get `$type` from a parameter of GET method. Like this:

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
```

As you know, If `$_GET['type']` is not available, that query will set `NULL` instead of `$type`.

---

Now I want to know, should I check it like this?

```
$type = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : null;
```

Or that condition is useless?

Comment: What do you get from `$_GET['type']`? Is it an integer, string?

Comment: It depends on how you want/need the value stored.  NULL is itself a value that is not zero.  Also, you can set a default in the database table to NULL.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I get that from URL, and it is a integer

Comment: @durbnpoisn I have set `NULL` in the database for that column. So I don't need to that condition?

Comment: try with `if(!empty($_GET['type'])) { $type = $_GET['type'] }` , empty can check both that either it is set and not empty

Comment: No.  You don't.  Because if it comes in blank, the database will write it NULL.

Comment: `$type = !empty($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : null;` - *better*.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I afraid of another thing, A PHP-fatal which says you don't define `$type` when I want to use if into the query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Then that condition is mandatory?

Comment: @stack it's not "mandatory", using a ternary with a conditional `empty()` is better than `isset()` as using `isset()` could always be TRUE and if your db will accept NULL. If not, replace `null` with `"no value"` if varchar. If `int` or other, then replace with a boolean or your choice of replacement.

Comment: normally i only do this if($var['something']) {$var = $var['something'];} doesn't gives any problem, in query, I get NULL in the entries if not set.

Comment: Get params usually come as strings. `isset` is a good way to check.  However if it is not set, I would set the php variable to blank string.  Otherwise you will insert NULL into the database.  If that is what you want to do then ok.

Comment: or you could replace the ternary with an `if isset and not empty`, that also works, or the contrary `if not set and is empty`; only you know ;-) remember to use a prepared statement though.

Comment: what to do with these many comments/answers(?) - you've been given enough now to decide. cheers and happy holidays.

Comment: PHP nulls would only become an SQL null if you're using prepared statements. a php null inserted into a string, e.g. `$foo = null; echo "The null is -> $foo <- here";` would simply print the null out as a zero-length string. the only way to use a php null as sql null via string building is to change your php null into a literal string with the characters `n`, `u`, `l`, and `l` in it.

Comment: @MarcB look this: `www.example.com/?q=12`. Now what happens if it insert `...table(OtherRow) values($_GET['OderArg'])` ? *(I use pdo)* ? Actually I want to know, Do I need to check `$_GET['OtherArg']` and set it to `null` if it not exist? *(because I want to insert `null` if it isn't exist)*

Comment: then you'd literally get `...values()` because a null var becomes a zero-length string. you'd need `$val = isnull($somevar) ? 'null' : $somevar`-type stuff, and be VERY mindful of sql injection attack vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If null value would be accepted and the entry can safely be made with it then no need to check for null value.

Obviously if null would not be accepted elsewhere in the program then you would need to validate it and set the field to not accept it. In this case i would validate as you have and proceed with the database entry only when the value would be accepted by the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_GET['type'])) 
{ $type = $_GET['type'] 
}
```

That should take care of your problem :).

Answer (score 0):

You **always** need to check if a variable exist or valid before you enter to the SQL query

```
if ( ! isset($_GET['type'])) {
   die('no value given');
}

$secured_type = mysqli_escape_string($_GET['type']); // SQL Injection secure

INSERT INTO table(type) values($secured_type);
```

Comment: If you use PDO you would be better off - it's better than mysqli

Comment: Instead of `die` command, the OP could use try and catch for an exception. `if ( ! isset($_GET['type'])) { throw new Exception('no value given');`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $type = '';
 if(!empty($_GET['type'])) 
    { 
          $type = $_GET['type'] 
    }
?>
```